# How to get the number of years between two java.util.Date?

Tags: java, gwt

How to get the number of years between two `java.util.Date`?

**Note:** using only `java.util.Date`

Comment: So, by the note, I take it you can't use the Calendar / GregorianCalendar classes?

Answer (score 9):

How accurate do you need to be?  If approximate is good enough, then I'd do

```
long msDiff = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
int yearDiff = (int)(msDiff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365.25);
```

Comment: that wont compile - you will need an explicit cast to int.

Comment: +1 (modulo the cast) - using just java.util.Date you won't get more accurate without duplicating a bunch of GregorianCalendar.

Comment: This is not correct for leap years as the year 1900 was not a leap year (being devidable by 100, but 2000 was as it is devidable with 400)

Comment: @Drejc - this code doesn't attempt to compensate for leap years at all.

Comment: Despite you say this is not accurate, I think is dangerous: it will give different results depending on the time (hour of the day) of the Date objects.

Comment: @sinuhepop, which part of "approximate" are you having problems with?

Comment: By the way, I'm assuming this is GWT client side, which is why I didn't suggest using Calendar because it's not available.

Comment: @PaulTomblin: I didn't notice it was for GWT, so I've deleted my answer. I understand what approximate means :). But I'm talking about another kind of problem. Imagine you calculate the age of a person (using new Date() as the second parameter). Five minutes later, without changing of day, same calculation may give you a different value. In my opinion this is a strange behaviour that, at least, would be documented and known.

Comment: Anyway, if Calendar can't be used in GWT, maybe your solution is good enough for client side, as you said. Maybe I would set time to midnight in both dates before calculate.

Comment: If the "5 minutes" between the calculations spans midnight of the birthday, you've got the same problem.  Calculating the integer number of years between two dates is always going to have that problem, no matter whether you use Date, Calendar, JodaTime or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to use *[java.util.Date](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)*??

If you would relax this constrain and allow usage of **[Joda Time - Java date and time API](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/index.html)** you could have your task done like that:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Period;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final DateTime now = new DateTime();
    out.println(new Period(now.minusYears(2), now).getYears());
    out.println(new Period(now.minusYears(2).plusHours(1), now).getYears());
  }
}
```

Output result is:

```
2
1
```

If you can't use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/index.html) use *[java.util.Calendar](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)*.

Comment: Since the question is tagged "gwt", I assume the question is about what can be done client side using the gwt api, which does not support Calendar or Joda Time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the getTime method for each Date object and do the subtraction. Convert the result to years.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, since this question is tagged under GWT, that you are trying to do date math in a 
GWT application.  GWT's emulation library implements the deprecated function Date.getYear(), in which case you can just do date2.getYear() - date1.getYear().

Using deprecated functions isn't the best, but appears to be common practice in the GWT development world.

Comment: So the difference between "31 December 2011" and "1 January 2012" is 1, as is the difference between "1 January 2011" and "31 December 2012"?  That may be what is required, but I doubt it.